# How to add criteria "Non" blank to AVERAGEIFS

Tags: excel, vba

The following works but on blank cells I get `#DIV/0!`

```
With ws.Range("D2:D" & lRow)
        .Formula = "=IF(B2<>B1,AVERAGEIFS(D:D,B:B,B2),"""")"
        .Value = .Value
 End With
```

I have tried (other variations on this as well)

```
.Formula = "=IF(B2<>B1,AVERAGEIFS(D:D,B:B,B2, B:B,"<>"),"""")"
```

but does not work

Thanks

Comment: I do this.  =IF(B2=0," ",A2/B2) to eliminate the #div/0 so if i'm dividing A2 by B2 if B2 is empty or zero it will not show that message.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try